# Displaying GeoJSON data on mapboxgl in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, geojson

I have created this GeoJSON document for waterStations

```
var waterStation = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
  {
    type: 'Feature',
    properties: {
     title: 'Water Refill Station',
     description: 'Description to be added...'
    },
    geometry: {
     type: 'Point',
     coordinates: [-120.4295379, 37.3634714]
    }
  }]};
```

Then I have followed the mapboxgl tutorials to create data points on a map with popups. However now I have built a csv to GeoJson converter and would like to change the variable waterStation in the following code to geoJson, which is the name of my new variable.

```
waterStation.features.forEach(function(marker) {
  console.log(geoJson.features[1]);
  console.log(marker);
  var refill = document.createElement('div');
  refill.className = 'water-station';
  refill.appendChild(document.createElement('i'));
  new mapboxgl.Marker(refill).setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates).setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: 25}).setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>')).addTo(map);
});}
```

My issue is that the forEach function will not output either of those console.log() executions when I make the change from waterStation to geoJson. A copy of how I am doing my csv to geojson is listed below.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Papa from 'papaparse';
var results = {};
var geoJson = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: []
};

axios.get(`path to my csv file`).then(res => {
  var csvString = res.data;
  results = Papa.parse(csvString, {
    delimiter: ",",
    header: true,
    dynamicTyping: true
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < results.data.length; i++) {
    geoJson.features.push({
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [
          results.data[i].longitude,
          results.data[i].latitude
        ]
      },
      'properties': {
        'title': results.data[i].title,
        'description': results.data[i].description
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a quick and short answer to this. Because of the way axios works the `.push()` does not load at the same time as outside the call. To fix this I just dropped the popup `forEach` loop inside the `.then()` and it will display all the data at the same time.